# Extending external module with d.ts in typescript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, amd

I am building a nodejs application using typescript. I'm using several external libraries like express.js. As many, this library as well designed to be extendable.

I'd like to extend it by adding a custom method. What is the typescript best practice to do so?

I wanted to inherit a class from it, but its d.ts doesn't define any classes (obviously). I can extend the interface:

```
declare module Express {
    export interface Application {
        foo();
    }
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to actually implement it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add members to `Application` directly *unless* you want to make a reusable library that other people should use. If that is indeed the case you will need function interception (http://basarat.github.io/this-and-prototype/#/apply).

I recommend just making a utility function.

Comment: Interceptions, mixins, utility functions are not OO approach. Not really what I was looking for. Am I right if I assume that there is no clean solution?

Comment: If you want to change the way `Application` works, interception is the way to go